# LZW compression generation file bigger than original

Tags: c++, compression, lzw

I have a text file and I think I implemented the LZW algorithm correctly, but the compressed file is getting bigger than the original.

I'm not running the LZW in the bytes of the text, but in the string instead.

I build a dictionary `[string:int]` and run it. I wonder if I should make it with the bytes instead of strings.

It also runs line by line of the file, instead of building just one dictionary for the whole file.

This is my LZW

```
map<string, int> D;                      //dictionary

int init(){                              //init dictionary with all single chars
    D.clear(); rD.clear();
    f(i,,256){
        D[string(1, char(i))] = i + 1;
    }
    return 257;
}

void encode(char* file){                 //LZW encoding method
    ifstream in(file);
    if (!in.is_open()) {cout<<"Could not open file"<<endl; return;}
    else {
        ofstream out("compressed.txt");
        for(string text; getline(in, text); ){

            int value = init();
            vector<int> idx;
            string p = "", c = "", pc = "";

            for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++){
                c = text[i];
                let s = p + c;
                if(D.find(s) != D.end()){
                    p = p + c;


          }
            else{
                idx.push_back(D[p]);
                D[s] = value++;
                p = c;
            }
        }
        idx.push_back(D[p]);
        int len = idx.size();
        f(i,,len) {out<<idx[i]; if(i == len-1) out<<" 0"<<endl; else out<<" ";}
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    cout<<"File compressed successfully"<<endl;

}
```

}

it just receives the address of the file and compresses it to "compressed.txt" file.

Comment: first of all you are outputing in text file but you need a binary

Comment: can you explain better what you mean by a binary? how do I do this and how would it help me?

Comment: you need to open your output file for binary output: `ofstream out("compressed.txt", std::ios::binary); `. Imagine that you are trying to write . 1234 to a file, in text mode it takes 4 bytes but in binary it takes only 2

Comment: it helped a little bit, but it wasn't enough... to convert it to binary is just change the ofstream this way? if it is, was not enough, 9mb turned into 16

Comment: @Daniel `out << ... << endl;` -- Why are you writing end-of-line characters to a binary file?  Also, the way you test this code to see if it really works is to get another, reputable, lzw program, not written by you, to see if it can lzw-decode the file you created.  If it can't do it or detects an error, then your code to encode the data is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of LZW is translate duplicated bytes into symbol, then write the symbols to bitstream.  The more duplicated bytes you have, the higher compression ratio you will get.  And the packed bits will save many space.

When you write a symbol as int to ofstream in that way its likely to use more than 4 bytes.  But with the packed bit, it should occupy from 9 bits to 16 bits depending on how you set it.  I think this is the main reason your output is bigger than expected.

Good luck.

Comment: why should I do to avoid this extra bit spending?

Comment: You have to pack the symbols.  for example the first 256 symbols use 9 bits, then the next 512 symbols use 10 bits and so on.  I don't remember exactly how its organized but it is not very difficult to understand and implement.